# Speed- and COG-aware trajectory interpolation/resampling using Python

Tags: python, interpolation, shapely, geopandas, trajectory

I have a set of ship trajectory points that were irregularly sampled and I would like to resample them to a fixed frequency (e.g. every minute).

Rather than just linearly interpolating between latitude and longitude, I would like to do this in a way that smooths according to course (`COG`) and speed (`SOG`).

Here is an example of the data:

```
Time              Lat    Lon    COG  SOG                                                         
2019-05-08 00:16  36.25  14.82  211  8.0
2019-05-08 00:28  36.23  14.80  221  7.7
2019-05-08 00:41  36.21  14.77  222  8.3
```

And here is a toy diagram explaining what I am trying to do. Instead of the first, I would like the second:
 [image]

Is there a simple way to achieve this using Python libraries? I am hoping there is a built-in method out there that can do this in a few lines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use Traja library (https://traja.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rediscretize.html) to resample your own data into the constant time interval that you want.